# Symfony 2.1 flash message after callback from external service

Tags: php, flash, session, symfony

I'm working on a symfony 2.1 server. it's a web portal representing a game catalog that works with a weekly subscription system.

Here is the situation:

1) user want to buy a subscription, so he click on "buy"

2) I redirect the user on an external service provider with a callback url

3) the user accept to buy

4) I'm getting called by the external service provider and I register the usersubscription

My problem is that, upon the external service provider callback , I cannot set up flash messages . I got no errors, but I got no message :).

I've noticed that my session is getting lost when the user is redirected to the service provider and then callbacked to my server and I guess this is the thing that "disable" the flashmessages.
Also, on my callback I got a return that is not rendered:

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('FrontendlandingBundle_account', array('_format' => 'html')));

I always use this and it's usally work.

I'm also using the same flash messages without redirecting users and it works fine.

Any idea of how can I get this messages to be correctly set up ?
Thanks for any help !

Sorry if I'm beeing unclear with some points.

More infos:
-I use redirect to call the service provider
-The service provider call me back as a POST request

**Controller callback**

//Here I do my stuff

//Register the user etc.

//Then after my user is registered I want to refresh the user status on his current page so I do:

`$this->_setFlashMessage(array('flashmessage_message' => 'Congratz', 'flashmessage_title' => 'Abonnement'));`

**_setFlashMessage:** `protected function _setFlashMessage($aFlash){ foreach ($aFlash as $k => $v) { $this->get('session')->setFlash($k, $v); } }`

And then in all my headers (twig):
`{% if app.session.hasFlash('flashmessage_message') %}`

After digging a little bit with @Wcool (thanks to him), I think my problem is now : "how to recover the session cookie after beeing redirected upon external service"

Comment: Just a 'might fix it' solution. Couldn't you set a cookie with true or false and let an error show (generic one)? As I said, it is a quick dirty fix (if it works).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping.
I'm not sure that I understood your idea.
I'm using flash messages to set variables that trigger javascript and allow me to call an external java android API to update theses infos.

Comment: I do not know much about javascript (yet, I'm learning it soon) so I think you can forget about my first suggestion. Javascript reads the flash message out of the session I assume? When (should) are the session flashbags set? Before or after the external callback? E.g. before a user enters the external page or should it be after? Would love to hear it, so I might be able to help further :)

Comment: Thanks digging with me !

My target is to set the flashbag After the user enters external page. 
For mor clearance here is the path user follow:

-User try to buy

-User get redirected to external

-User buy on external

-User get redirected to ME

-Here is where I try to set my flash message, in my "CallBackFromExternalAction"

-Here I do my redirect thing, in the same controller

Comment: If you do it AFTER the external callback (e.g. when a user is already back at the site), then it should just work according to my knowledge. Could you post some code and highlight the lines where you want the messages to be set? Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to read if you'd post it in your question :) Also, is it possible for you to post the PHP session cookie from the browser, before and after? This way we can check if the cookie gets lost (which holds identifier for server to retrieve session data). Thanks! Otherwise I think it's outside of my current scope knowledge, so you have to wait for someone else, sorry :(

Comment: I edited my message. 
I'm almost sure that the cookie IS lost. I'm not the guy who setted up this cookie so apologize if I sound a little "newbie" to you !

I checked sessions variable that I set before and after the callback. And all parameters get losts ! 

But what I don't understand is that even If my session get lost, should'nt have one new upon comming back on the page ?

Thanks again man

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are setting this Flash Message upon the external service callback. If so, the request comes from outside the browser, from another machine, and so the user session does not exist within that context, and so any flash message (which are attached to a session) will not get passed to the user. If this is true, you must return the user to your app and only then define the flashMessages.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for helping
When I get the call back, the user IS in my app. When the external service call me back, it trigger a piece of code in My app. it's in this piece of code that I try to set flash message and refresh the page. But maybe there is something I don't get... ?